# ActionId dependency in deploying Page Layouts

Tags: deployment, metadata-api, page-layout

I am trying to deploy changes from a a github branch into a Salesforce Sandbox but keep getting the following error(s):

```
Case-ACH Bounce Layout  Page Layout 0   0   The ActionId specified was invalid for ActionType QuickAction.
Case-ACH Bounce Layout - CS Page Layout 0   0   The ActionId specified was invalid for ActionType QuickAction.
Case-ACH Bounce Layout - CS - Lightning Page Layout 0   0   The ActionId specified was invalid for ActionType QuickAction.
```

The error message for all of them is `The ActionId specified was invalid for ActionType QuickAction.`. Everything that I have seen is to ensure that **Chatter** & **Notes** are enabled but both of these have been enabled for the target Org (& source org). I have also compared the page layout actions from the source to the target and they look to be the same.

Has anyone else experienced this issue? Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Other conversation(s): https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000kAo3IAE

Comment: So I was able to 'resolve' the issue by removing the 'Email' Action from the page layouts. Does anyone know why that is the case? I do see that someone stated they had to update their email deliverability but the source org was already set to 'All Emails'. Any insight would be appreciated.